# Setting Jenkins Environment Variable value via evaluation of command

Tags: shell, jenkins, command, environment-variables, evaluate

Anyone know how I can set the environment variable value based on unix terminal command in jenkins using inject variable or some other way.  e.g CurrentBranch=`ls /project/folder | grep my_name`.  This doesn't seem to work.  I want this command,ls /project/folder | grep my_name, to be evaluated and the result should be set to CurrentBranch.

Some reason CurrentBranch variable value never gets evaluated but rather it always has a value as this: `ls /project/folder | grep my_name`

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in a way so that it is available to *any* Jenkins task, which is written.

You can however write your Jenkins task so that all of them are executing a shell script, and then your question boils down to sourcing a suitable rc file (we use for instance zsh as a shell and have a special rc file just for Jenkins), and inside this file, you can set your environment in the usual way, i.e.

```
export $(ls /project/folder | grep my_name)
```

(Of course, grepping the output of ls in this way is not the best idea, but this is a different topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can save CurrentBranch in a file called env and inject that file into your job using [EnvFile Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin)

```
echo "CurrentBranch=`ls /project/folder | grep my_name`" > /tmp/env
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jenkins job configuration, check the checkbox "Prepare an environment for the run" .

select below checkboxes
    Keep Jenkins Environment Variables
    Keep Jenkins Build Variables

in the "Script Content" section, run below command to create properties file

```
echo "CurrentBranch=`ls /project/folder | grep my_name`" > /tmp/jenkins_job.prop
```

then in "Properties File Path" section, give this properties file with full path name.

now CurrentBranch variable will be avialable through out the build and can be access using ${CurrentBranch} .

Comment: helloworld, if the answer helps you. Can you mark as a correct answer, please?